# $\limsup_{n\to \infty}(n^n/n!)^{1/n} = e$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to understand how 
$$\limsup_{n\to \infty}(n^n/n!)^{1/n} = e$$

i.e., the fact that the power series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n^n/n!)z^n$$
has a radius of convergence of $\frac1e$

I haven't the slightest clue how to prove this, and am looking for any sort of nudge in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to use Stirling's approximation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) (otherwise it's a one line exercise), have you tried using the ratio test? It should lead you towards a well known limit...